# declaring local variables in c# expression trees bound to a block

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

My problem here is that I cannot get local variables to blocks in c# expression trees (e.g. System.Linq.Expressions) to work without throwing an exception despite function argument variables working perfectly fine.

By 'local variables' here, I don't mean closures. I mean variables that are specifically local to blocks in c# expression trees. Currently, I have a very bizarre case, where one expression tree works, and another throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: variable 'num' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

The working code is compiled from:

```
public static int Assign ()
{
    int num;
    int num2;
    num = 1;
    num2 = 2;
    return num + num2;
}
```

to the expression tree (debug view):

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`1[System.Int32]>() {
    .Block(
        System.Int32 $num,
        System.Int32 $num2) {
        0;
        0;
        $num = 1;
        $num2 = 2;
        .Return returnLabel { $num + $num2 };
        .Label
            0
        .LabelTarget returnLabel:
    }
}
```

This works normally. However, when my compiler tries to compile this:

```
public static int Assign ()
{
    int num = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    return num + num2;
}
```

as:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`1[System.Int32]>() {
    .Block(
        System.Int32 $num,
        System.Int32 $num2) {
        $num = 1;
        $num2 = 2;
        .Return returnLabel { $num + $num2 };
        .Label
            0
        .LabelTarget returnLabel:
    }
}
```

This block expression throws the invalid operation exception -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>   Additional information: variable 'num' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

What's really confusing here is that the only difference is caused by the random {0} - System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(0) expression seemingly making the error go away (the reason these exist is

Specifically, this problem doesn't appear for parameters defined in the lambda 
expression, for example, the compiler deals with:

```
public static Crappier<int> FieldAssign(int i, Crap thing)
        {
            thing.field = i;
            return new Crappier<int>(); ;
        }
```

fine outputting an expression tree:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`3[System.Int32,Sulieman.Crap,Sulieman.Crappier`1[System.Int32]]>(
    System.Int32 $i,
    Sulieman.Crap $thing) {
    .Block() {
        $thing.field = $i;
        .Return returnLabel { .New Sulieman.Crappier`1[System.Int32]() };
        .Label
            null
        .LabelTarget returnLabel:
    }
}
```

However, I specifically want variables that are bound to one block. The reason for this is that in the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("world");
}
```

This is valid c# code since although i is declared twice, it is declared to it's 
local scope. My compiler tries to account for this by compiling to:

```
*.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action>() {
    .Block() {
        .Block(System.Int32 $i) {
            $i = 0;
            .Loop .LabelTarget forContinueLabel: {
                .If ($i < 3) {
                    .Block() {
                        .Block() {
                            .Call System.Console.WriteLine("hello")
                        };
                        $i++
                    }
                } .Else {
                    .Break forBreakLabel { }
                }
            }
            .LabelTarget forBreakLabel:
        };
        .Block(System.Int32 $i) {
            $i = 0;
            .Loop .LabelTarget forContinueLabel: {
                .If ($i < 3) {
                    .Block() {
                        .Block() {
                            .Call System.Console.WriteLine("world")
                        };
                        $i++
                    }
                } .Else {
                    .Break forBreakLabel { }
                }
            }
            .LabelTarget forBreakLabel:
        };
        .Label
            3
        .LabelTarget returnLabel:
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this? I'm fairly certain I'm handling these local variables in totally the wrong way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind - this was a nasty bug where the assignment $num was referencing a different object but same name parameter expression which was different to the parameter expression in the block. Parameter Expressions with the same name are not necessarily the same parameter expressions!